# How to convert java.util.Date into current time in timestamp..?

Tags: java, sql

i am making a program in java.
i am using the following code

```
u.setLastlogin(new java.util.Date());
```

above function accepts parameter as `java.util.Date` but i want to store this value in a database table where the column is of type `timestamp`?

can any one help how to code so that i can insert the current timestamp of the system in the table. thanks.

Comment: What database access layer are you using? JDBC? Eclipselink?

Comment: i am using database of mysql over jdbc..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can convert `Date` to `Timestamp` as follows:

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

And if you want timestamp of current date:

```
new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Date now = new Date();
now.getTime();
```

Comment: He wants to know how to get the current time into the DB. Not how to output it to the screen...

Comment: what getTime() will return ..? will it b a timestamp..?

Comment: It will be a long, the number of milliseconds from 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000

Comment: It returns a long value, the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object. And it can be the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just issue an SQL statement:

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET LAST_LOGIN = NOW();
```

This is for MySQL. You should also find this helpful: [MySQL Date and Time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

**EDIT**
As Rambo requested, setting default value of a column to the actual timestamp (As per [MySQL: ALTER TABLE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) and [MySQL Data type default values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html)):

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ALTER MY_TIMESTAMP COLUMN SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: actually i want to convert the new java.util.Date() object into the current timestamp object.. nothing anything with database..

Comment: The new Date() is the current timestamp... I don't understand your problem... And if nothing about database, why did you add sql tag to it? That is confusing!

Comment: sorry if i confused u.. but it was just to mention that my column in the database table is of timestamp..

Comment: however your answer was useful to me as i got to know about NOW(); can u help me a bit more.. can u edit your answer how to set default timestamp in mysql..?

Comment: As for default timestamp, do you mean the default value of a column, that is of a timestamp type?

Comment: @Rambo I updated my answer, but I can't test it, as I don't have a MySQL instance at hand right now...

Comment: Why the downvote? It always helps the community (not to mention the chap who wrote the answer) to publish the cause of why it doesn't help somebody...

Answer (score 0):

With JPA:

annotate lastLogin with: `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)`

With JDBC:

[PreparedStatement#setTimestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp,%20java.util.Calendar%29)

Answer (score 0):

use this to `java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(new Date().getTime());`

```
u.setLastlogin(timestamp);
```